# Plotting image icon on top of a static image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To better understand my question, please refer to the following image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Hvh.jpg

I have two images. The map image and the blue circle image. Please note that the map image is only an image and I am not using the Google Maps API to display it. As it will always be the same view. What I am trying to accomplish is trying to move the blue circle along the black line and I want it to be able to move the circle dynamically with a simple incremental int number

So if my int push = 5

The circle on the map will move up by a certain distance and int push = -5 will bring it back.

Currently I have a simple html background with the map image and have places the blue circle on top with a image tag as follows

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/ZZHnuaf.png'); width:517px;height:374px;">
    <img width="30px" height="30px"src="http://i.imgur.com/MUlVIyg.png" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/9VqQ7/

Any help on how I can get started would be greatly appreciated! Also thank you very much for taking your time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

So the main idea is having a function `f(v)` which returns an object with a x and y coordinate. Then you position the marker image relatively inside the map and change the left and top style attributes to move it around.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/9VqQ7/2/

Comment: Hello Hugo T I apologize it took so long to follow up. But can you explain to me what the purpose of this part in your code is for?     for (var i  = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        map.decrement();
    }

Comment: I mostly put it there for demo purposes. Decrement and Increment moves the marker up and down along the line.

Comment: Hey Hugo, another quick question. These two lines             marker = document.getElementById("marker");
            this.setPosition(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y); seem to be causing an issue on IE7 any ideas?

Comment: @BaconJuice I can't say on a straight hand what's not working. It might be that the variable INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y and marker aren't being resolved correctly.

Comment: I made a post here with more details. Can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693598/ie7-css-block-relative-position-with-javascript-bug