# IE7 css block relative position with Javascript bug

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a simple JS script that moves a CSS block at a specific path when a value is given to it.

You can take a look at the code here http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/6DGfb/

This code seem to work fine on Chrome and Firefox except IE7.

The error I get from IE is as follows

```
Line: 27  
Char:13  
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method  
Code: 0  
URL: http://localhost/test/js/plot.js
```

Line 27 is as follows

```
    marker = document.getElementById("marker");
    this.setPosition(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y);
```

Below is my full JS script for your reference.

```
(function () {
    var INITIAL_X = 550,
        INITIAL_Y = 152;

    // f(v) -> {"x" : x, "y" : y}
    var calculatePosition = function (value) {
        var result = {};

        result.x = INITIAL_X -  value / 9;
        result.y = INITIAL_Y + 0.117  * value/ 9 ;


        return result;
    }

    var map = {
        marker : null,
        value : 0,

        setPosition : function (x, y) {
             marker.style.left = x + "px";
             marker.style.top  = y + "px";
        },

        init : function () {
            marker = document.getElementById("marker");
            this.setPosition(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y);
        },

        increment : function () {
            this.value++;
            var result = calculatePosition(this.value);
            this.setPosition(result.x, result.y);
        },

        decrement : function() {
            this.value--;
            var result = calculatePosition(this.value);
            this.setPosition(result.x, result.y);
        }
    };

    map.init();

    for (var i  = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        map.increment();
    }
})();
```

Thank you for taking your time to read this and helping me solve this issue.
As always any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
marker = document.getElementById("marker");
```

`marker` does not resolve to a property of your `map` object as your code seems to expect; instead, it resolves to a property of the global object. IE, however, populates the global object with properties whose names corresponding to the IDs of elements within the page and then doesn't allow you to overwrite these. This means that in IE there is already a global `marker` that cannot be overwritten.

This is one good reason why implied globals like your `marker` should be avoided. The easiest fix is to change references to `marker` to `this.marker`:

```
    setPosition : function (x, y) {
         this.marker.style.left = x + "px";
         this.marker.style.top  = y + "px";
    },

    init : function () {
        this.marker = document.getElementById("marker");
        this.setPosition(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y);
    },
```